# Eclipse 2020 "Java Source Compare" Diff Editor: What's the purpose of multiple colors (red & green)

Tags: eclipse

Before, in Eclipse 2017-2018, Java Source Compare (upon double-clicking in Git Staging) was straightforward: the Left/Right panes show the change with only 1 color.

Now in Eclipse 2020-03, I see multiple colors. There is a **single block** below which was replaced with a one-liner. What's the purpose of the red color below? Where is it coming from? This is all one block that was replaced.

[image]